# Simple Prediction Using Multiple Regression with Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have an item list and its associated sales month wise for Dec,Jan,Feb,March. etc. Is there a possibility to predict Apr month sales in advance based on past 5 to 6 months data. I tried using linear regression of sklearn using X_train and X_test split. But that helps me to predict how accurate my model has become but I want to predict an estimate of next month beforehand. I'm new to Python so every help is valuable. Thank you

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Item Name": ["ABC", "XYSD", "BBDSS", "WLSA", "XABC"],
    "Oct-Sales": [0, 0, 0, 3, 2],
    "Nov-Sales": [0, 1, 1, 3, 0],
    "Dec-Sales": [0, 3, 0, 3, 3],
    "Jan-Sales": [1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
    "Feb-Sales": [0, 2, 0, 1, 1],
    "Mar-Sales": [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
})

X_final = data[['Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr']].copy()
Y_final = data['May'].copy() 

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
    X_final, Y_final, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 0)

lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,Y_train)

X_final_pred = lr.predict(X_final)

print(X_final_pred)
```

Comment: Don't use images in your question, please. Also, please provide a code example of what you did, and where you want have problems. Thank you.

Comment: @MacOS Please find below code I prepared:-                                                                          data= pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Data_File.xlsx")

Comment: X_final=data[['Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr']].copy()                                      
Y_final=data['May'].copy()                                                                                                                  X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_final, Y_final, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 0 )                                                                                                              
lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,Y_train)                          
X_final_pred=lr.predict(X_final)    
print(X_final_pred)

Comment: P{lease do **not** post code in the comments - edit & update your post intstead. Plus, question has nothing to do with `r` or `scipy` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code.

```py
X_final = data[['Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr']].copy()
Y_final = data['May'].copy()
```

This makes no sense because `Apr` can not be a predictor because you don't have data for this month. In addition, `May` does not exist in your `data frame`. In fact, none of this columns exist in your data frame. You need to add `-Sales` to the keys.

Your problem is more difficult than you think. And in addition, it does not only relate to programming issues. For the following reasons.

Frist, you want to predict sales for different products. This means that it does not make sense to train one model for different products, especially if they are from different product categories.

Second, you seem to not have much training data. Indeed, you seem to don't have enough to catch seasonal effects.

> Is there a possibility to predict Apr month sales in advance based on past 5 to 6 months data.

Of course. You can just do it. There is also no restriction on the model you can try (if we forget the training size for a moment). You can use a decision tree, random forest, or a linear regression, as you did.

> I tried using linear regression of sklearn using X_train and X_test split. But that helps me to predict how accurate my model has become but I want to predict an estimate of next month beforehand.

I don't know what you want exactly. However, if you ask if it is possible to predict two timestamps into the future, then the answer is yes.

The code to train a model on April using all of your timestamps is

```py
X_final = data[['Oct-Sales','Nov-Sales','Dec-Sales','Jan-Sales','Feb-Sales']].copy()
Y_final = data['Mar-Sales'].copy() 

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
    X_final, Y_final, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 0)

lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,Y_train)

y_pred = lr.predict(X_final)
```

You can then use this model to make predictions for april with

```py
X = data[['Nov-Sales','Dec-Sales','Jan-Sales','Feb-Sales', 'Mar-Sales']].copy()
y_pre_apr = lr.predict(X)
```

And if you want to predict two timestamps ahead you can do

```py
X_final = data[['Oct-Sales','Nov-Sales','Dec-Sales','Jan-Sales']].copy()
Y_final = data['Mar-Sales'].copy() 

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
    X_final, Y_final, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 0)

lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,Y_train)

y_pred = lr.predict(X_final)

# Make predictions for May
X = = data[['Dec-Sales','Jan-Sales', 'Feb-Sales', 'Mar-Sales']].copy()
y_pred_may = lr.predict(X)
```

However, this is a simple example and will not yield good results. Working with temporal data is complicated.

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for your insights. They are actually helpful and that is actually what I was looking forward to. As you mentioned next month sales numbers for n number of items. Since I am at my learning stage I will also try Decision tree and Random forest on the above data to understand which model gives me the best output.